# Is there a way to add extra uses of Tactician?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, fighter, archetype

I'm wanting to build a Fighter with the Tactician archetype, but the tactician ability is SO LIMITED, only a maximum of 4 times per day (or 5 if you go Cavalier) at level 20.

Is there a feat or other mechanic that I'm somehow missing that allows for extra uses of this ability akin to Extra Channel or Extra Hex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Practiced Tactician (from the Advanced Player's Guide) is the feat you're looking for.

> Benefit: You can use your tactician ability to grant allies a teamwork feat one additional time per day.
> Special: You can gain Practiced Tactician multiple times. Its effects stack.

[database link](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Practiced%20Tactician)